# Open Zoom and Start Meeting via Windows Task Sheduler

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I am wanting to run a simple URL call.

It works as a shortcut.

```
zoommtg://zoom.us/start?confno=MYZOOMMEETINGID
```

I now want to use Windows Task Scheduler to start this about 30 times per week for yoga classes

I have seen the solution to be create a task, start program powershell.exe and then Add Arguments area I put

```
-Command "Invoke-WebRequest zoommtg://zoom.us/start?confno=MYZOOMMEETINGID”
```

When I run this I get...

```
Command : The term '-Command' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
-Command "Invoke-WebRequest zoommtg://zoom.us/start?confno=5720401698 ...

CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-Command:String) [], CommandNotFoundException FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

What's with the Powershell?

In Task Scheduler create a Task to launch your preferred Browser, with the full URL as an Argument, as follows:-

"C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" https://us02web.zoom.us/j/YourMeetingID?pwd=VeryLongPassword

Set the trigger for each occurrence.

DONE